# Conditionally copy rows to different sheet if leftmost cell has ANY value

Tags: vba, excel

New to the site; would greatly appreciate your help!

I want to conditionally copy rows from "sheet1" to "sheet2".

Condition: The leftmost cell in the row (column "A") has ANY value (numbers or text).
*I do not want to copy rows that are blank.

I'd like to run the VBA macro for all of sheet1(specifically columns A through L and rows 10 - 9999).

If you guys need any more info, please let me know; Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Without writing your code for you, this will get you started:

```
    Private Sub Find_Non_Blanks()
    Dim cell As Range, rowOut As Long
    rowOut = 0
    For Each cell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A10", "A9999")
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            rowOut = rowOut + 1
            Debug.Print rowOut & ":", "A" & cell.Row, cell.Value, cell.Formula
        End If
    Next
    Debug.Print "Found " & rowOut & " rows to be copied."
    End Sub
```

You can put this code on any sheet, userform or module. It will produce the same output regardless of which sheet is currently active, or what the current selection is.

For speed, reliability and ease-of-maintenance, your VBA should operate directly on ranges without selecting or activating them. In other words, try hard not to use these keywords in your VBA code:

```
      Select, Selection, Activate, ActiveCell
```

Comment: Thank you for the headstart.  This helps a BUNCH